# Message returned is null

Tags: java

Hi i have a problem with my server, everytime i call "dload" the file gets downloaded but i can't use the other commands i have because they get returned as null. Anyone who can see the problem in the code?

Server :

```
public class TCPServer {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        ServerSocket server = null;
        Socket client;
        // Default port number we are going to use
        int portnumber = 1234;
        if (args.length >= 1) {
            portnumber = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
        }
        // Create Server side socket
        try {
            server = new ServerSocket(portnumber);
        } catch (IOException ie) {
            System.out.println("Cannot open socket." + ie);
            System.exit(1);
        }
        System.out.println("ServerSocket is created " + server);
        // Wait for the data from the client and reply

        boolean isConnected = true;

        try {
            // Listens for a connection to be made to
            // this socket and accepts it. The method blocks until
            // a connection is made
            System.out.println("Waiting for connect request...");
            client = server.accept();
            System.out.println("Connect request is accepted...");
            String clientHost = client.getInetAddress().getHostAddress();
            int clientPort = client.getPort();
            System.out.println("Client host = " + clientHost
                    + " Client port = " + clientPort);

            // Read data from the client
            while (isConnected == true) {

                InputStream clientIn = client.getInputStream();

                BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                        clientIn));
                String msgFromClient = br.readLine();
                System.out.println("Message received from client = "
                        + msgFromClient);

                // Send response to the client

                if (msgFromClient != null
                        && msgFromClient.equalsIgnoreCase("sum")) {
                    OutputStream clientOut = client.getOutputStream();
                    PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(clientOut, true);
                    Double[] list;
                    list = new Double[5];
                    String value;
                    int i;
                    try {

                        for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
                            pw.println("Input number in arrayslot: " + i);
                            value = br.readLine();
                            double DoubleValue = Double.parseDouble(value);
                            list[i] = DoubleValue;
                        }
                        if (i == 5) {
                            Double sum = 0.0;
                            for (int k = 0; k < 5; k++) {
                                sum = sum + list[k];
                            }
                            pw.println("Sum of array is " + sum);
                        }
                    } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                }

                if (msgFromClient != null
                        && msgFromClient.equalsIgnoreCase("max")) {
                    OutputStream clientOut = client.getOutputStream();
                    PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(clientOut, true);
                    Double[] list;
                    list = new Double[5];
                    String value;
                    int i;
                    try {

                        for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
                            pw.println("Input number in arrayslot: " + i);
                            value = br.readLine();
                            double DoubleValue = Double.parseDouble(value);
                            list[i] = DoubleValue;
                        }
                        if (i == 5) {
                            Arrays.sort(list);
                            pw.println("Max integer in array is " + list[4]);
                        }
                    } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                }

                if (msgFromClient != null
                        && msgFromClient.equalsIgnoreCase("time")) {
                    OutputStream clientOut = client.getOutputStream();
                    PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(clientOut, true);
                    Calendar calendar = GregorianCalendar.getInstance();
                    String ansMsg = "Time is:, "
                            + calendar.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY) + ":"
                            + calendar.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
                    pw.println(ansMsg);
                }
                if (msgFromClient != null
                        && msgFromClient.equalsIgnoreCase("date")) {
                    OutputStream clientOut = client.getOutputStream();
                    PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(clientOut, true);
                    Calendar calendar = GregorianCalendar.getInstance();
                    String ansMsg = "Date is: " + calendar.get(Calendar.DATE)
                            + "/" + calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH) + "/"
                            + calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR);
                    ;
                    pw.println(ansMsg);
                }
                if (msgFromClient != null
                        && msgFromClient.equalsIgnoreCase("c2f")) {
                    OutputStream clientOut = client.getOutputStream();
                    PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(clientOut, true);
                    String celciusValue;
                    boolean ifRead = false;

                    try {

                        pw.println("Input celcius value");
                        celciusValue = br.readLine();
                        ifRead = true;
                        if (ifRead == true) {
                            double celcius = Double.parseDouble(celciusValue);
                            celcius = celcius * 9 / 5 + 32;

                            pw.println(celcius);
                        }
                    } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                }

                if (msgFromClient != null
                        && msgFromClient.equalsIgnoreCase("dload")) {

                    OutputStream outToClient = client.getOutputStream();
                    if (outToClient != null) {
                        File myFile = new File("C:\\ftp\\pic.png");
                        byte[] mybytearray = new byte[(int) myFile.length()];

                        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(myFile);

                        BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(fis);

                        try {
                            bis.read(mybytearray, 0, mybytearray.length);
                            outToClient.write(mybytearray, 0,
                                    mybytearray.length);

                            outToClient.flush();
                            outToClient.close();
                            bis.close();
                            fis.close();

                        } catch (IOException ex) {
                            // Do exception handling
                        }

                        System.out.println("test");

                    }
                }

                if (msgFromClient != null
                        && msgFromClient.equalsIgnoreCase("quit")) {
                    client.close();
                    break;
                }
                // if (msgFromClient != null
                // && !msgFromClient.equalsIgnoreCase("bye")) {
                // OutputStream clientOut = client.getOutputStream();
                // PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(clientOut, true);
                // String ansMsg = "Hello, " + msgFromClient;
                // pw.println(ansMsg);
                // }

                // Close sockets
                if (msgFromClient != null
                        && msgFromClient.equalsIgnoreCase("bye")) {
                    server.close();
                    client.close();
                    break;
                }

                msgFromClient = null;
            }
        } catch (IOException ie) {
        }
    }
}
```

Client:

```
   import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;

public class TCPClient {
 public static void main(String args[]) {

  boolean isConnected = true;
  Socket client = null;
  int portnumber = 1234; // Default port number we are going to use
  if (args.length >= 1) {
   portnumber = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
  }
  try {

   String msg = "";
   // Create a client socket
   client = new Socket("127.0.0.1", 1234);
   System.out.println("Client socket is created " + client);
   // Create an output stream of the client socket

   OutputStream clientOut = client.getOutputStream();
   PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(clientOut, true);
   // Create an input stream of the client socket
   InputStream clientIn = client.getInputStream();
   BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
     clientIn));
   // Create BufferedReader for a standard input
   BufferedReader stdIn = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
     System.in));

   while (isConnected == true) {
    System.out
      .println("Commands: \n1. TIME\n2. DATE\n3. C2F\n4. MAX\n5. SUM\n6. DLOAD\n7. QUIT");
    // Read data from standard input device and write it
    // to the output stream of the client socket.
    msg = stdIn.readLine().trim();
    pw.println(msg);
    // Read data from the input stream of the client socket.



    if (msg.equalsIgnoreCase("dload")) {
        byte[] aByte = new byte[1];
        int bytesRead;
        ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

        if (clientIn != null) {



            try {
                FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("C:\\ftp\\pic.png");
                BufferedOutputStream bos = new BufferedOutputStream(fos);
                bytesRead = clientIn.read(aByte, 0, aByte.length);

                do {
                    baos.write(aByte, 0, bytesRead);
                    bytesRead = clientIn.read(aByte);
                } while (bytesRead != -1);

                bos.write(baos.toByteArray());
                bos.flush();
                bos.close();

                System.out.println("File is successfully downloaded to your selected directory"+ "\n" +"*-----------------*"+ "\n" );

            } catch (IOException ex) {
                System.out.println("Couldn't dowload the selected file, ERROR CODE "+ex);
            }

        }
    }else{

        System.out.println("Message returned from the server = "
                  + br.readLine());
    }
    if (msg.equalsIgnoreCase("bye")) {

     pw.close();
     br.close();
     break;
    }
   }
  } catch (Exception e) {

  }

 }
}
```

Comment: There are **no other commands you have**.

Comment: First problem: `baos.write(aByte)` should be `baos.Write(aByte, 0, bytesRead)`. It's also not clear why you've got `baos` at all, when you could just write to `bos` the whole time...

Comment: Your question seems to be saying: "Here's the code which works; what's wrong with my other code, which doesn't work?" That's like a mother with two sons taking the healthy one to the doctor and expecting the doctor to diagnose what's wrong with the one who's sick at home.

Comment: The server part is only working 1 time then i get null.

Comment: what's getting null? pasting stacktrace, more code to communication between server/client will be helpfull..

Comment: why you do not put the server in a runnable class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

debugged your code and have two hints:

1)

don't surpress your exceptions. handle them! first step would to print your stacktrace and this question on SO wouldn't ever be opened ;-) debug your code!

2)

```
outToClient.flush();
outToClient.close(); //is closing the socket implicitly
bis.close();
fis.close();
```

so in your second call the socket on server-side will already be closed.

Comment: If i don't close the socket the dload command won't work a second time and if i close it i can only run it one time so i don't know what to do.

Answer (score 0):

first thing:

```
if (args.length >= 1) {
    portnumber = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
}
```

This can throw a NumberFormatException, and because args[0] is passed by the user you should handle this.
reading the code also this gave me a problem:

```
double DoubleValue = Double.parseDouble(value); // LINE 104
```

Throwing a NumberFormatException when I give c2f as command to the server. You definitively need to handle this exception anywhere in your code and give proper answer to the client, something like:

```
try{
    double DoubleValue = Double.parseDouble(value);
}catch(NumberFormatException e){
    // TELL THE CLIENT "ops, the number you inserted is not a valid double numer
}
```

(in short example, starting from this you have to enlarge the code)

---

```
while (isConnected == true) {
```

I cannot see it! why not use this?

```
while (isConnected) {
```

---

```
if (msgFromClient != null && msgFromClient.equalsIgnoreCase("sum")){
```

can be:

```
if("sum".equalsIgnoreCase(msgFromClient)){
```

in this case you have no problem with the NullPointerException. (if msgFromClient is null the statement is false).

---

By the way, date and time command are working fine for me. Check the others.

To fix dload i think you have to delete the line:

```
outToClient.close();
```

(EDIT: sorry to maxhax for the same answr, didn't see your answer while writing this)

Comment: Thanks for taking your time to check the code, the problem i have with dload is that if i remove outToClient.close(); the file will not be downloaded. Stuck at this problem at the moment and not sure how the handle it :(.

Comment: try with

    ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream()); 

or try to reconnect a new socket after you close the outputStream

Comment: Thanks man, i made it so that the server and client reconnects everytime i use the dload so it works now :)